# 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint

I am trying to download excel sheet from share point to my local machine path.

Here is what i tried:

```
public class ReadAndDownloadController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {           
        const string username = "**********";
        const string password = "**********";            
        const string url = "https://globalfunctionsshare.nam.citi.net/sites/otdrrm/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/sites/otdrrm/Documents/tools/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker%2020210702.xlsx";
        var securedPassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
        var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);

        DownloadFile(url, credentials, @"C:\ImpDocs\temp.xslx");

        return "XYZ";
    }              

    private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl); ----> Here I'm getting Error
        }
    }
}
```

But as i am trying to run this code i am getting an error as

"An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I Don't understand what is the actual issue here. Share point url is correct, my credentials are correct also the path where i am downloading exists.

This cost me an entire day. Please if some one can help it will be of a great help

Comment: Is there any other way to validate your credentials? For example, can you try to log on manually with a known-good tool? Or can you check server logs to see the reason for the 401?

Comment: _[We don't recommend that you use the `WebClient` class for new development. Instead, use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks)_

Comment: @aepot : Do you have any source code with HttpClient because I had a bit knowledge on WebClient. Please if you can help me with an example or link with HttpClient

Comment: You may easily find hundreds of examples here. It's very popular class.

Comment: You may start learning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).